# HP Officejet Pro X476dw with Windows Server 2012 R2 - Manual Feed Paper Size / Type Prompt

Tags: hp, printing

I have activated the Print Server role on my Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard server and added a new HP Officejet Pro X476dw, deployed to the clients via Group Policy. The printer is setup with preprinted A4 paper in Tray 1 (Manual Feed) and plain A4 in Tray 2. Everything works fine except when printing to Tray 1 from a client, the printer displays a prompt saying that the paper size or type is mismatched (it says "Insert A4 - Preprinted"), which is to be confirmed with "OK" before the job is actually started.

I have search the web for this problem, in many cases the answer is to select media type "Any" ord "Unspecified" in "Printing Defaults" on the "Advanced" tab in the printer's properties on the server. However, I do not have any of these options, so I set it to "Preprinted".

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you asked your vendor for support?

Comment: I have exactly the same printer at home and my daughter uses Tray 1 for printing photos - this isn't via W2012 of course but she chooses regular A4 - not the preprinted version/type - have you tried that as it works for her.

Comment: @Chopper3: I will try setting Tray 1 to A4 Plain. Will report back.

Comment: @Chopper: Changed the setting to "Plain", still getting the prompt :(.

Comment: Shouldn't the manual feed always prompt you though? I'd consider getting [the extra tray](http://store.hp.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/PDPStdView?catalogId=10051&urlLangId=-1&langId=-1&productId=110700&storeId=10151) for this printer, rather than expecting the manual feed to be automatic.